# iOS 7 Custom UISegmented control has 1 pixel gap

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a 1 pixel gap at the end of my `UISegementedControl` which only appears in iOS 7.

[image]

I am not sure why this is appearing or how to resolve it. I would greatly appreciate guidance on diagnosing and fixing the issue.

Comment: is this happens if text of title fits without trimming end?

Comment: Did you fix the problem? I have the same with a normal UISegementedControl

Comment: @Laurenz Glück, not yet. Was hoping for more answers.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary okay, too bad... if I find something I'll post it here :)

Comment: @JasonMcCreary did you find out what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by making a new project with just the UI control and whatever other elements are relevant, to see if you can replicate the problem without other code.

What does it look like in the storyboard editor? I assume manually increasing the width doesnt fix the issue?